# Moment of inertia of a Cardan/Hooke joint?

Tags: experimental-physics, rotational-dynamics, home-experiment, moment-of-inertia, applied-physics

I'm working on a model that approximates a rotating body as a double Cardan joint: one of [these guys](https://www.google.com/search?q=double%20cardan%20joint%20gif). In my scenario, torque is applied to the center shaft and both end shafts are free. The angle between all 3 shafts remains constant throughout the rotation. The rotational axes of the two end shafts are in the same plane, but they're neither perpendicular nor parallel to each other and I am having difficulty figuring out where to start. If anyone can give me a start in the right direction or a term to google, I would be really grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the equations of motion with Euler Langrange Method and constraint equation.

[image]

Assuming that $\psi=0$ so both coordinate system are parallel.

[image]

Where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the Euler angle and $R_1,R_2$ the rotation matrix between the body fixed coordinate system and inertial system. your system have 5 generalized coordinates.

Comment: Instead of photographed hand-writing please use [MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for the equations.

Comment: Forgive me if your comment answers this already, but in my model the torque on both end shafts is the same. If I use a single cardan joint like you show, the torque from the motor is applied to the spider/cross, not to either shaft. I know that's not how these joints work, but it works for the model (also probably why I'm getting confused).

Comment: @springonastring to answer your question  I need drawing  of your model.

Comment: Here's a diagram of the model: http://imgur.com/a/2UmhR1E (Forgive my using imgur to host it: I'm not sure how to do it here yet.) In the model, there are two cardan joints and three spindles, A, B, and C. There is a string wrapped around the center spindle, C. When the entire body is released, gravity pulls on it in the direction shown and the tension in the string causes the center spindle C to roll without slipping, which in turn applies an equal torque to spindles A and B.

Comment: The angle between spindle A and C is equal to the angle between B and C and both remain constant throughout the rotation. The rotational axis of each spindle is shown in its corresponding color. The fact that it has three different rotational axes that arent parallel or perpendicular means I cant just add each one's mass moment like I could for a rigid body. I know the rotations are coupled, but I'm still not sure how to approach the problem. Also, since torque on C is caused by tension in the string, which depends on the mass moment of the entire body, I can't work backwards from torque..

Comment: https://imgur.com/user/elipankiewic101